# Where does GetVersionNumbersString take data from in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, getfileversion

In order to get the file version I wrote this:

```
#define FileVersion GetVersionNumbersString("...\Client.exe")
[Setup]
VersionInfoVersion={#FileVersion}
```

File version is a string in `"0.0.0.0"` format. In my case it's `5.0.6.5` and it does not change.
Where does `GetVersionNumbersString` take that data from? How is `5.0.6.5` formed?

Comment: Whoever builds the executable embeds the version information into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version is taken from the version info of your .exe file. If you check the "Details" tab of the executable properties, the `GetVersionNumbersString` corresponds to the "File version" entry (`5.17.9.10905` in this case):

[image]